# Strange border-color issue

Tags: css

I'm creating a toplist of users where I use CSS3 border to create a white-border for the ranking number. Its viewable here: http://www.cphrecmedia.dk/musikdk/stage/channelfans.php

However it seems theres a black border after the border, which I find very very strange. It seems its spill from the background-color.

Its a very minor issue, but I'm very interested in why this actual happens. Does anyone know why? The CSS is very very simple, so it shouldn't happen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prevent this leak outside border, you need to declare a `background-clip` property with `padding-box`. This shall resolve your issue.

**The Code change:**

```
#tf span h6 {
  background: #333333;
  border: 4px solid #F9F9F9;
  border-radius: 99px;
  color: white;
  font: 700 30px/80px arial, sans-serif;
  margin-left: -26px;
  padding: 5px 13px;

  /* The important part to remove the overflow/leak: */
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; 
  -moz-background-clip: padding; 
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice solution. Tested on site and it works (in Chrome).

Comment: That worked! Is there a good explanation on why this helps? Or is it just "the usual hack"? FYI theres no need to use the prefixed versions of the "background-clip". The normal one works fine in all the browsers

Comment: True @MortenHjort, but to be on the safer side, declaring prefix attributes for cross browser compatibility should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is a spill issue:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24998

Answer (score 0):

You can add this

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2pt 2pt black;
```

inside your

```
#tf span h6 {

}
```

in `.css file`

like:

```
#tf span h6 {
    border-radius: 99px;
    background: #333333;
    color: white;
    font: 700 30px/80px arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 13px;
    border: 4px solid #F9F9F9;
    margin-left: -22px;

    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2pt 2pt black;
}
```

it will generate black shadow to your rounded box, so more or less it will become attractive and removes that box kind of issue.

Comment: I just tried it, but that just gives a shadow outside the spill. And if inset its inside the spill. Its really strange. Its also a issue in Chrome