# IE11 border radius and border bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I have an odd visual bug in IE11 as you can see in image here >

[image]
<sub>(source: [jonwallacedesign.biz](http://www.jonwallacedesign.biz/ie11.png))</sub>

See the odd effect on corners of the white "WHY USE US" `li` button....

The combination of `border-radius`, `background-image` and `border: 1px solid #colour` seems to be creating this odd horrid effect.

Anyone know of a solution to fix?

CSS of the `LI` is:

```
background-image: url("../images/core/primnavItemBG_sprite.png");
background-position: 0 0;
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 6px;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
color: #2062AF;
font-family: 'Montserrat',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
margin-right: 5px;
outline: medium none;
overflow: hidden;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
```

Comment: I've noticed this on ocassion since they first added support for `border-radius` in IE.

Comment: Perhaps this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935209/strange-border-color-issue/21935662?noredirect=1#comment33227979_21935662

Comment: Curious why you are using background-image with an actual image instead of CSS3 gradients?

Comment: What about drawing borders with box-shadow and use a linear-gradient for browsers which understands it ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wlJca

Comment: Using a BG image as much more cross browser compliant! CSS3 grads are very messy I think!

Comment: As an add-on to what @BramVanroy said, [here](http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/) is a resource that shows how to do CSS gradients, including vendor prefixes that support IE 6+. Probably the maximum support you would need now days.

Comment: I too am experiencing this in IE11 and Microsoft Edge on Windows 10. I can't reproduce in IE11 on Windows 8.1, however. I'm using solid background colors, no fancy gradients or anything.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is device or graphic setting oriented in newer windows. I've seen this occur on my TV with vivid video settings but not on my desktop or laptop.

Comment: have you tried giving it `box-sizing:border-box` property?

Comment: can you upload your background image and share a working fiddle.. or snippet in SO itself

Comment: @BryanCorey im also experiencing this issue in IE11 on win10. edge seems to work. its doing this all across my entire app which is either solid fills or 1-2px borders (boxes, inputs, etc are all exhibiting this) - super annoying. did you figure it out?

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me. I am not sure if you have the same problem as me.
I was getting slight white borer just around the corners.

background-clip: padding-box;

Answer (score 0):

Please try this inside conditional CSS block.

```
background-image: url("../images/core/primnavItemBG_sprite.png");
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; /*In Border color use color same as background color otherwise use border-size:0*/
box-shadow: none;
outline: none;
```

hope this will fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

<style>
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a background-image why not use http://css3buttongenerator.com/ to recreate this button and save on any additional requests and loading time. I was able to re-create your button and your gradient just fine in IE 11 using the above generator. Picture attached;
[Button image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlRsw.png)

Answer (score -2):

Adding a solid BG colour to IE10 + fixed this... seems like an IE bug trying to render CSS3 bits...

Comment: I have this exact same problem, but my button is already using a solid BG color. I'm seeing these strange lines on the left side of every element that I put border-radius on. What was your full code for the fix?

Comment: I have the same issue with a solid background. I also wouldn't mind seeing a solution.

Answer (score -2):

You turn on IE10 mode by adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />` to head section and will work normally.

Comment: This answer was given almost 20 min before yours.