# Border-radius displaying issue in Internet Explorer 10 and 11

Tags: internet-explorer, padding, css

I have a div with border-radius. It is displayed with some kind of fragemnts in IE10 and IE11.

What is the cause? How do we fix this?

[image]

Visit this site with either IE10 or IE11 to see the effect:
http://css3pie.com/demos/border-radius

Visit to fiddle: http://goo.gl/pKLe89

Comment: I can't replicate your problem in IE11 or Firefox in your fiddle or on the CSS3PIE site. Could it be a problem with your video?

Comment: all looks fine in IE11...

Comment: it's your specific problem,change your computer- maybe IE11 Rendering probelm with your VGA Card or something like that

Comment: Check the setting of Graphics Acceleration in Internet Options|Advanced.

Comment: @Teemu thank you, this is the answer. I had to activate Softwarerendering, so it must be some issue with the graphics card. Might be because I am running the windows in a VM. I apologize for cursing on IE this time.

Comment: curious, what is your base OS? Is it windows? MAC, etc. Sort of wondering if this is a general VM issue or maybe tied to a particular platform OS/VM stack.

Comment: using macbook pro 15-inch, Late 2011, osx 10.9.2, Parallels 9.0.24217.

Answer (score 0):

IE10 and IE11 both support border radius. Although, some claim that the [***4 missing pixels***](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2012/11/rounded-corners-and-gradients-in-ie10-the-4-missing-pixels/) do exist, you may  be able to go that route.
Another option is to atempt to hack it.

```
-ms-border-radius: 10px;
```

Comment: There's also a bug in IEs: when you have a `legend` tag within a `fieldset`, `fieldset` loses its border radius.

Answer (score 0):

These are the issues come issues will come if you are not defined meta tag in HTML header.  this meta will resolve problems.

{}

here some usefull link: [IE11 border radius and border bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018567/ie11-border-radius-and-border-bug)