# ie11 broken background image on rounded corners

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

JsFiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q5AjL/
Screenshot from jsfiddle in ie11, dev mode off:
[image]

Screen shot from my actual site:
[image]

Has anyone seen this before? In ie11 some of the borders have this strange broken affect.

It seems that the semi transparent image is breaking around the rounded corners. How on earth can i fix this? Sigh.. ie.. you are the pain in the side of my web design life.

```
.small-card{
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.trans{
    background-image: url(/png/transparent/white/40_percent.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border: solid 1px #fff;
}
```

This is ie11. When i turn on devloper mode the issue vanishes! So confusing.

[image]

I really don't understand what is going on. And as above, as soon as i turn on developer mode the issue disappears. It only occurs where there is a rounded corner involved.

Comment: Have you tried looking at RGBA for the background rather than an image? This will improve the performance of the page as there are fewer HTTP requests required, and will also be more flexible. I'd imagine it would resolve the artifacting issue as well. The Developer Tools seems to give us a clue as is not well with the page - what doctype are you using? Does the HTML validate?

Comment: the page does validate yes, i have replicated the bug on jsfiddle (put link in post). I am really quite stumped here. Does anyone else see the strange affects i am seeing?

Comment: Your Fiddle works fine on my IE11, without artefacts. I also tried different zoom percentages, to be sure.

Comment: ahhhh... that has just confused me even more!

Comment: I have just added a screen shot from jsfiddle in ie11 from my machine.

Comment: I believe you, but here is mine: http://i60.tinypic.com/357lgko.png  Using IE 11.0.4 (11.0.9600.16521) on Windows 7.

Comment: :) no i believe you.. it must be just my installation of ie. Man i blummin well hate ie. It is never simple. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22723955/border-radius-displaying-issue-in-internet-explorer-10-and-11#comment34631682_22723955).