# Why is border radius not showing up in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

How do I get border radius to work in IE?

I have an `<input type=image>` element in my html. In my css I have `border-top-right-radius:12px;` and `border-bottom-right-radius:12px`.

Everything works in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE11, the image shows up with square corners instead of rounded corners.

I also have this meta tag in my html:
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />`

The code is below.
CSS:

```
body .overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 114, 198,.7);            
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
body .layer {
    background: url('photo-homebanner.jpg') 55%;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body .goldenDiv {
    width:665px;
    height:326px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:100;
    margin-top:-38px;
    margin-left:-8px;
}       
body h1 {
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    padding-top:22px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    font-size:45px;
}
body h3 {
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-weight:100;
    padding-bottom:14px;
}
body h3.hidden {
    visibility:hidden;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:220px;
    left:190px;
}
body input:focus {
    outline:none;
}
body .prettyInput {
    align-content: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 70px;
    margin-left: 106px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 61px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 40px;          
}
body .inputOverlap {
    position:absolute;
    top:167px;
    top:166px\9;
    left:485px;
    z-index:3;
    border-top-right-radius:12px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:12px;
}
body hr {
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    top: 77px;
    left:120px;
    align-content:center;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    body .inputOverlap {
        position:absolute;
        top:168px;
        left:485px;
        z-index:3;
        border-top-right-radius:12px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:12px;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="goldenDiv">
        <div class="layer">
            <div class="overlay">
                <h1>Stay ahead of industry news!</h1>
                <hr width="450px"/>
                <h3>Let us send you the latest from our Marketing Department.</h3>
                <input id="emailAddress" type="text" class="prettyInput" required placeholder="Your email address here" />
                <input onclick="sendEmail()" type="image" width="57px" height="57px" class="inputOverlap" src="submitButton.jpg" />
                <h3 class="hidden" id="hiddenValidation">*Please enter a valid email address.</h3>
                <h3>100% privacy, no spam, just news.</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Insert <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" /> into head. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018567/ie11-border-radius-and-border-bug

Comment: hmm this did not work.

Comment: Seems to be a bug with how IE renders border-radius on button tags. Add a border to the `input[type="image"]` and you'll see it renders the image on top of the border (ie: ignoring the border bounds). You could easily sidestep it by wrapping the `input[type="image"]` in a `div` that applies the same size/border constraints, is what you abs-pos into place, and has `overflow:hidden;`

Comment: Oh and you should really declare the `height` and `width` attributes you used in your css instead. Your form already explodes on LTE IE 8, no sense in using the insanely-deprecated attributes, and moves that into the CSS for ease of changing.

Comment: @abluejelly wrapping it in a div worked! Thanks! Want to post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with IE's rendering of `input[type="image"]`- if you give it a `border` attribute you can see that the image is rendered ignoring the `border-radius` property.

Easiest way to fix would be to wrap the `input[type="image"]` in a `div`, apply the positioning, border, and sizing properties to the `div` (apply sizing to the `input[type="image"]` as well), and tag the div with `overflow:hidden;`.

---

Stylistic notes (unrelated to the problem):

`border-radius: 0 12px 12px 0;` means the same thing as

```
border-top-right-radius:12px;
border-bottom-right-radius:12px;
```

but is less than half the locs. I suggest only using the verbose versions if you need to adjust only one corner and want whatever the others were set to to be preserved.

The `height` and `width` attributes on your image should be set in the CSS not on the `input[type="image"]`. Those attributes have been frowned upon for a very long time, especially since the CSS ones accomplish the same thing.